# How do I add headers for requests from an API?

Tags: javascript

I just started learning Javavascript yesterday so if I'm missing something completely obvious, I apologize.

I am pulling information from the [Last.fm api](https://www.last.fm/api/intro) with the following code:

```
    let textarea = document.getElementById('username_entry').addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevents the submit on Enter
        
        // ---- Attributes ----
        const username = document.getElementById('username_entry').value;
        const api_key = MY_API_KEY;
        const url = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.gettopartists&user=" + username + "&api_key=" + api_key +"&format=json";
        const users_top_artists = [] // List to hold the users top 50 artists
        const users_similar_artist_urls = [] // List to hold the users top 50 artists

        // ---- Fetch the Json data ----
        fetch(url).then(function(resp) {
            return resp.json();
        }).then(function(data){

            // ---- Append each of the users top 50 artists to a list ----
            for(let artist of data.topartists.artist){
                users_top_artists.push(artist.name);
            }

            // ---- Iterate through each of the users top artists and find the Json file for thier similar artists. Append those urls to a list ----
            users_top_artists.forEach(artist => {
                const formatted_artist = artist.split(" ").join("+"); // replace spaces with + for searching
                const similar_url = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getsimilar&artist=" + formatted_artist + "&api_key=" + api_key + "&format=json&limit=10";
                users_similar_artist_urls.push(similar_url);
            });

            // ---- Iterate through each of the similar artists urls and pull the names of each artist. Append the names to the similar artists list.
            users_similar_artist_urls.forEach(similar_artist_url => {
                fetch(similar_artist_url).then(function(resp) {
                    return resp.json();
                }).then(function(data) {
                    for(let artist of data.similarartists.artist){
                        console.log(artist.name);
                    }
                })
            });
        });
      }
});
```

The documentation states the following:

> Please use an identifiable User-Agent header on all requests. This
> helps our logging and reduces the risk of you getting banned.

I have only been able to find descriptions on its use but can't find any examples of use with Javascript. Can anyone point me in the right direction so I can figure out how to add the correct header to my requests?

Please don't hesitate to ask if there is anything I can add for clarity. Thank you for your time.

Comment: [Supplying Request Options with fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_request_options)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue after following [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_request_options) from @TylerRoper as well as [this reference](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-3.7).

The sample code:

```
// Example POST method implementation:
async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  // Default options are marked with *
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *client
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
  return await response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
}

postData('https://example.com/answer', { answer: 42 })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data); // JSON data parsed by `response.json()` call
  });
```

My implementation based on the code above:

```
fetch(url, {
        headers: {
            "User-Agent": "MyAppName/Version# (Language=Javascript; Platform: Linux)"
        }
    }).then(function(resp) {
        return resp.json();
    }).then(function(data){...
```